# Vue.js routes does not work using router-link

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, routes, vuejs3

i make a project using vue js. in the nav bar i put menu home and about which is will go direct to each page when it's clicked. there is no error when i run the project but the router doesn't work when i clicked the menu.

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './routes'

import './assets/main.css'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

**routes.js**

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from '@/components/Home.vue';
import AboutMe from '@/components/AboutMe.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        name: 'Home',
        path: '/',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        name: 'AboutMe',
        path: '/aboutme',
        component: AboutMe
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})


export default router;
```

**app.vue**

```
<div class="container header-item" id="app">
      <img src="./assets/Logo.svg" alt="Logo">
      <div class="nav">
        <router-link to="/" class="nav-item">HOME</router-link>
        <router-link to="/aboutme" class="nav-item">ABOUT ME</router-link>  
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please share the code of `App.vue`

Comment: cannot share the full code due to max characters

Comment: Are you using `router-view` in your App.vue

Comment: i don't use router-view. i've tried to put <router-view/> right after router-link but turns out it make a mess in home menu. it displays anything from another page.

Comment: did url changed ? if yes, than you need to add router-view in app.vue file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to add `<router-view/>`

add it on your app.vue file after the nav section.
Example:

```
      <div class="nav">
        <router-link to="/" class="nav-item">HOME</router-link>
        <router-link to="/aboutme" class="nav-item">ABOUT ME</router-link>  
      </div>
      <router-view/>
```